# Expo-cli start command leaves app on blank white screen

Tags: react-native, expo

This issue keeps coming and going and i'm really confused. I have used the command `expo-cli start` to start all of my react-native projects but sometimes it will run and i'll connect my phone to only find it displays the splash screen and then just an empty white screen. If I go into my other projects the same thing happens. This happened before and just fixed itself randomly but it has seemed to happen again and I don't know what to do. No error displays and the console says the javascript bundle has built successfully and my phone has connected. I am using the latest version of expo-cli

Comment: I faced a similar issue. On uninstalling and installing expo app on android, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if for android just type this in terminal to see the error message that you'd be able to more easily see in Android Studio:

adb logcat | grep ReactNativeJS

or

change http urls to https in your project (preferred)

Comment: i'm using Atom on a Mac and running expo on my android phone. Also I cant see where to change http to https